# How to build a MDDropdownMenu and its items on pressing a Button?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

As my app has many screens and is almost done building the frontend i dont want to change the screen manager(`<root widget>:`) and `class MainApp(MDApp):`. Please help me on how i can add a MDDropdownMenu on pressing package weight button on my home screen without changing the layout of my code. Not only the below mentioned code but i have tried different ways to implement it but faced lots of errors. Please help and Thanks in advance.

**MY main.py file**

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
import json
from datetime import datetime
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton ,MDRectangleFlatIconButton 
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel, MDIcon
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineListItem
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu, MDMenuItem

class HomeScreen(Screen):

    def drop(self):
            self.dropdown= MDDropdownMenu(items= {"viewclass": "MDMenuItem","text":"option1"}, width_mult=4)
            self.dropdown.open()
    


class RootWidget(ScreenManager):
    pass


class MainApp(MDApp):
    
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette= "Green"
        return RootWidget()
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

**My design.kv file**

```
<HomeScreen>:
     GridLayout:
         cols: 1
         padding: 20, 20
         spacing: 10,10
         size_hint: 1,0.87
         MDRectangleFlatIconButton:
             icon: 'weight-kilogram'
             text: "Package weight"
             size_hint: (0.55,1)
             on_press: root.drop()
 <RootWidget>:
     HomeScreen:
         name: "home_screen"
```

This is the image of my app home screen

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the `caller` in your `MDDropdownMenu()` call, and the `items` is expected to be a list of dictionaries.

Try changing your `kv` to include an `id` for the `MDRectangleFlatIconButton`:

```
<HomeScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        padding: 20, 20
        spacing: 10,10
        size_hint: 1,0.87
        MDRectangleFlatIconButton:
            id: caller   # ADDED
            icon: 'weight-kilogram'
            text: "Package weight"
            size_hint: (0.55,1)
            on_press: root.drop()
```

The `id` is used to identify the `caller`.

Then create the `DropDown` in a `on_kv_post()` method, and the `drop()` method just opens the `DropDown`:

```
class HomeScreen(Screen):
    def on_kv_post(self, base_widget):
        caller = self.ids.caller
        self.dropdown = MDDropdownMenu(caller=caller, items=[{"viewclass": "MDMenuItem", "text": "option1"}], width_mult=4)

    def drop(self):
        self.dropdown.open()
```

The `on_kv_post()` method is executed after the `kv` rules have been executed, so that the `ids` are available.

The `MDDropdownMenu` is not created in the `drop()` method, as recommended in the [documentation](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/menu/index.html#wrong).

Comment: John Anderson thank you so very much for your help. It is working. I struggled 3 days to implement this. But the problem is the MDDropdownMenu is opening in different places on my home screen. how do i specify it to open right under my package weight button?

Comment: Add `position='bottom'` to the `MDDropdownMenu()` call.

Comment: John Anderson thank you so much for your time sir. i already tried giving position but that dose not work. i have posted another question for that problem. Please check it out and consider helping sir.